# 2 versions of Dojo on one page

Tags: dojo

I need to run 2 versions of Dojo on the same page. 
There is some old code acessing dojo with the typical dojo.byId etc.
this should stay. I wan't to use the latest version for my development. Can anyone help me with the syntax for the package. So that I can use myDojo or myDijit or myDojoX ?

Answer (score 2):

The following should help with getting two versions running on a page.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/multiversion.html

However, the reason you stated in the question to run two versions is not valid.  `dojo.byId`and other non-AMD methods, such as `dojo.addClass`, `dijit.byId` are still supported in 1.9.